# unity only works the first boot

Tags: 11.04, unity, ati, graphics

Ubuntu 11.04 Unity works fine when booted to try out from CD.  After install, Unity works the first login but not after that.  Classic doesn't work either.  I can only use Classic no-effects.

Why does unity only work when booted from CD?

I have an Inspiron 1721, AMD Turion 64, ATI Radeon graphics.

BTW: Ubuntu 10.04 worked fine.

Comment: Don - have you installed any "additional drivers" for your graphics ? - n.b. make sure you have connected to the internet first before opening that window.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type 'additional drivers'

You should then see if you have any driver installed or to install for either wireless or graphics card

It may for instance come up with a choice to download and install an fglrx package for your graphics card

Let us know if it is installed.

If it is not, then install it.

If it is installed, then it may require some other work such as deactivation or reinstalling.